# Jupyter kernel for C++ on mac

Tags: c++, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

The `xeus-cling` [Jupyter kernel](https://github.com/QuantStack/xeus-cling) for C++ looks great.

According to the [installation](https://github.com/QuantStack/xeus-cling):

`xeus-cling has been packaged for the conda package manager on the linux platform.`

Does this also work on mac?

(Comment [thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15808809) on Hacker News suggests that it does not, so I wanted to confirm.)

If not, are there any alternative Jupyter C++ kernels for mac?

Comment: I tried installing xeus-cling few weeks ago and turned out the corresponding OSX conda package was missing. I gave up for lack of time/interest, but, if things haven't changed, I suppose you'll need to build it yourself ...

Comment: ok, just tried building and obviously it needs full llvm; that's the problem; as of now, I'm not going to install it on this machine to avoid conflicts with apple's toolchain. I'll try on a different machine tomorrow ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `xeus-cling` kernel has now been packaged for OS X.

From a clean conda environment, you can run

```
conda install xeus-cling notebook xwidgets widgetsnbextension -c conda-forge
```

Also, you can try it live online with the binder link at the top of the xeus-cling readme.